# Get HTML response in a var C#

Tags: c#

I am getting response of HTML in a variable var. When i first wrote the code it gives me the correct output but after doing some different stuff and came back that function it causes problem and give some error "Value cannot be Null" and i debugged the Code it shows me the correct output in properties search box but shows me incomplete output on Immediate Window. I do not know where is the error!!!

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document1 = webGet.Load("http://www.lfp.fr/ligue1/feuille_match/76107");
var club1 = 
    from foo in document1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='club']") 
    select foo;
```

I have Rebuild the solution restart my PC but problem is still there. I am using HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping all in a try catch for a more detailed exception? PLease post the exception

Comment: Have you stepped through in the debugger? Have you verified that `document1` loads properly? Have you looked at what's inside it? There's little way for us to know which values are null in your application.

Comment: Are you sure it is this snippet of code that is causing the error? Your code looks correct to me. Try posting the entire content, especially the `InnerException`, of the exception you are getting.

Comment: Yes, it was working perfectly sometime before. ANd i used Try catch Exception Handler and it gives me the error "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source" @CR41G14

Comment: I have moved this code most upper side of Function but Error is still there. @Alex Essilfie

Comment: @Alex Essilfie i have told you that My property Search box gives me correct output in properties Search box but in Immediate Window it is incomplete.